# Excel. List every variation of a value range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get Excel to list every variation of a certain value.

If A1= ABC1904
&  A2= ABC1910

I'd like column B to list.

ABC1904
ABC1905
ABC1906
ABC1907
ABC1908
ABC1909
ABC1910

Comment: couldn't you just use the advanced filter or sort + remove duplicates?

Comment: I want it to generate every variation.  not me list it and remove dups

Comment: ah, I see what you're after.  Is your data always 3 characters and 4 numbers, or will that vary. Is A1 always the first of the counter and A2 always the end?  You may have to provide a more representative use case to get a complete solution.

Comment: always 3 characters.  4-5 numbers.  a1 = start a2=end.  If I get an example I can change it as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could do w/ a purely formula solution:

```
=LEFT(A$1,3) & MID(A$1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A$1&"0123456789")),LEN(A$1))+MIN(RIGHT($A$2,1)+0,ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)
```

It leaves a bit to be desired because you'll have a bunch of duplicates if you drag the formula too far down.

If you're not opposed to a VBA solution, you could give this a go:

```
Sub VariationOfValue()
Dim startNumber     As Long, _
    endNumber       As Long, _
    counter         As Long

Dim leadingString   As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
    counter = 1

    With Sheet1
        leadingString = Left(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value, 3)

        startNumber = Evaluate("=MID(A$1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A$1&""0123456789"")),LEN(A$1))") + 0
        endNumber = Evaluate("=MID(A$2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A$2&""0123456789"")),LEN(A$2))") + 0
        Do While startNumber <= endNumber
            .Range("B" & counter).Value = leadingString & startNumber
            counter = counter + 1
            startNumber = startNumber + 1
        Loop
    End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

Does basically the same thing, but only until the last number is reached.  Either way, hope one or both of these helps out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to have a few columns to achieve this then it is really not very difficult.

Col A is your starting data. [ABC1904 and ABC1910}

Col B contains equations =VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)) which gives the numeric part of the strings. [1904 and 1910]

Col C contains equations =IF(OR(C2=B$2,C2=""),"",C2+1) - except C1 which is just =b1 
- this gives the series of numbers you want {1904 to 1910]

Col D contains equations =IF(C1="","",LEFT(A$1,3)&C1)
- this puts the text back on the front of the numbers [ABC1904 to ABC1910]

..this would be clearer with a screenshot but I apparently do not have enough reputation to post one